# Get live data from a queue of ActiveMQ

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, activemq-classic

I have to fetch live data from a queue of ActiveMQ installed on a remote server.

I am planning on using AJAX to get the live data. The following link describes how to do it 
http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html

But when I insert the described commands on the necessary location, I am not able to fetch the data.

I also checked the following links to learn how to get data from server to PHP script, but in vain ...

http://activemq.apache.org/using-apache-activemq.html

My Question is, how to I link my existing PHP page to fetch data from server and display it using AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ AJAX support is an optional feature, as is the STOMP protocol, which are the two most promising methods for getting PHP to integrate with ACtiveMQ.

You should talk to the folks managing the ActiveMQ server and work out which mechanism they want used to get access to the system.

If they do want STOMP, a more messaging oriented protocol, there is reasonable PHP support: http://php.net/manual/en/book.stomp.php